# Structures in C giving erroneous output

Tags: c, structure

I not a C programmer by any means but have been using PHP and Perl for many years.  Am assisting someone with a C program using structures.

I have the following code  -

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 2
#define max 2

struct student   //initialising...
{
    char coursecode[100];
    char coursename[10];
};

main()
{
    int i,z;//for the loops

    struct student stud[10];


    printf("Enter available course name and their corresponding codes\n");

    for(z=0;z<max;z++)
    {
        printf("Course Name:  ");
        scanf("%s",&stud[z].coursename);
        printf("Course Code:  ");
        scanf("%d",&stud[z].coursecode);
        printf("-----INFORMATION RECORDED-----\n");
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("SUBJECTS");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    for(z=0;z<max;z++) // Prints them back to the screen
        {
            printf("%s               %d\n",stud[z].coursename, stud[z].coursecode);
            printf("\n");
        }


    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

}
```

I get the following output

````
Enter available course name and their corresponding codes
Course Name:  Art
Course Code:  101
-----INFORMATION RECORDED-----

Course Name:  Biology
Course Code:  102
-----INFORMATION RECORDED-----


SUBJECTS

Art               6485496

Biology               6485704




--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.501 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .```
````

Am not sure why it giving this result and would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Correct the scanf from %d to %s and it works.  @user3121023, what is the & usually for?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `char[100]` to store your course code and you are asking for an int with the `%d` formatter ! 
You can rather ask for a string with `%s` or `%99s` as suggested in comments, or if your coursecode is just an int you can maybe make the coursecode attribute an int.

Answer (score 0):

Your course code is declared as an array of chars, `char coursecode[100]`. Therefore, in

```
scanf("%d",&stud[z].coursecode);
```

The `"%d"` format specifier shouldn't be used, and you also don't need the `&` (address of) operator. Do

```
scanf("%99s",stud[z].coursecode);
```

instead, where `99` is to limit the input and `"%s"` is to read input into a char array. Do this also for `scanf("%s",&stud[z].coursename);` so that it reads `scanf("%9s",stud[z].coursename);`. You should also change your `printf` to use the `"%s` format specifier instead.

Answer (score 0):

At line 7 you define an array of char `char coursecode[100]` (which is used as String type).

First of all when you read an input with: `scanf("%d",&stud[z].coursecode)` you are asking for int variable

And then you print using again `%d` which is used for `int` type variables

You have two possible solutions depending how you want your `coursecode`:

1)
You can use instead `%s` in your scanf and printf (the same way you are doing with the coursename[] ),
so your code would change:

`scanf("%s",&stud[z].coursecode)`

`printf("%s   %s\n",stud[z].coursename, stud[z].coursecode);`(maybe using `\t` as spacing)

This way you are treating the course code as a "String".

OR

2) You declare your`char coursecode[100]` into `int coursecode` and keep your scanf and printf the same

Answer (score 0):

In your structure, you have indicated that coursecode is a character. But then you are referencing it as %d, as if it was an integer. Change it to %s and yo good to go